# How to use cloudinary url2png within asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloudinary

I have seen some sample code in cloudinary for using url2png, in the below link

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/url2png_website_screenshots_addon#create_website_screenshots

For example nodejs implementation like below

```
cloudinary.url("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg", 
 { type: "url2png",
   crop: "fill", width: 150, height: 200, gravity: "north"
   sign_url: true });
```

I could not find any sample code for using the same in c#.net web app.

Can any one suggest me how to implement cloudinary's url2png in c#.net

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a .NET example equivalent to the code you've shared:

```
cloudinary.Api.UrlImgUp
  .Type("url2png")
  .Transform(new Transformation().Crop("fill").Width(150).Height(200).Gravity("north"))
  .Signed(true)
  .BuildUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg");
```

Comment: This code "only" generates an HTML image tag of a Cloudinary valid URL. You need to access the returned URL in order to generate the screenshot. Then, it'll be stored in your Cloudinary account.

Comment: @ItayTaragano it didnt work as expected.Not sure why. But we are postponing this implementation for later. Thanks for your answer!